# toggling a class of several items with same base id number variable

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I have a function that toggles a class for an id, I have to list them individually right now, but they're all going to be called space_BORDER_somenumber.  Is there a way to set up the function so instead of listing them all it will toggle all of the items with the base id?

```
$(function() {

nebula_slide_TOTAL.ev.on('rsBeforeAnimStart', function() {
        $('#space_BORDER_1').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
        $('#space_BORDER_2').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [attribute-starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector, like so:

```
$('[id^="space_BORDER_"]').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
```

However, using that selector is slower than applying a class to all of those elements and using a regular class selector, so that may be a better solution if you have access to change the HTML that defines the elements.

Comment: hmmm, I have a list of items, but they're not in the same container, adn basically if one gets clicked I'd like taht one to get one class and the rest get all of another, as there are more of them it would be easier to not have an ever growing list, you know?

Comment: @loriensleafs That seems like a separate issue to the one you asked about in your question, but there's nothing overly difficult about what you're attempting to do. Have you tried it for yourself yet?

Comment: well that's what I had come up with for a solution, I had tried it earlier using a list and sibulings, but these arn't in the same container, so that's why I had resorted to just listing them separately.